# How to log all the details to log table and send an email if any stage fails I'm ADF using databricks notebook

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I have multiple stages in ADF ,how to log all the information to a log table and send an email if any of the stages fails In ADF.
Is their any pyspark generic code available which I can use in databricks?

Answer (score 0):

To send email notification for failed stage in ADF, you don’t need to store all logs in table format.

You need to use Logic app to send email if you get error in any stage of ADF pipeline.

Follow below steps:

1. Create a Logic App workflow named `SendEmailFromPipeline`

[image]

2. You can trigger Logic App from a pipeline using a Web activity.

[image]

3. Add dynamic messages with system variables and expressions

[image]

You can use `system variables` and `expressions` to make your messages dynamic. For example:

```
@activity("CopyData").output.errors[0].Message

@activity("DataFlow").error.Message
```

For detail steps you can follow [Official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-send-email)